# How to retrieve data from drop down list selection to a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to learn how to program and this is my first project. I know i should read the tutorials but  im kinda stuck with it. really wanting to accomplish it by myself, but it's getting frustrating.. can somebody at least guide me in the right direction?
So, how do i echo the data to the table cells based on the drop down list selection?
Any help much appreciated.
code so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/uFEPn/3/

```
<select>
    <option>-- Select lot --</option>
    <?php
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('pl_base');
    $query="SELECT DISTINCT  lot_number FROM pl_table";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while(list($lot_number)=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<option value=\"".$lot_number."\">".$lot_number."</option>";
    }
   ?>
    </select>
</br>

<table border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th width=80 height=30>Lot<br/>number</th>
    <th width=110 height=30>Description</th>
    <th width=90 height=30>Pallet<br/>number</th>
    <th width=60 height=30>Net</th>
    <th width=60 height=30>Gross</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td rowspan="5">echo results here</td>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
  </tr>
    <td> # </td>
    <td colspan="3">#</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>&</th>
    <th>&</th>
    <th>&</th>
    <th>&</th>
  </tr>

  </table>
```

the table in data base:

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+
|    id   |   lot_number   | descr  | pallet_number  | net     | gross |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+
|    1    |       111      |  black |         1      |  800    | 900   |
|    2    |       111      |  black |         2      |  801    | 901   |
|    3    |       111      |  black |         3      |  802    | 902   |
|    4    |       222      |  white |         1      |  800    | 900   |
|    5    |       222      |  white |         2      |  801    | 901   |
|    6    |       222      |  white |         3      |  802    | 902   |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing the lot number in a select element will not update directly using php.
since php is a server side language you would have to submit the data as a form and then display it.

```
    <?php 
     mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('pl_base');
        $query="SELECT DISTINCT  lot_number FROM pl_table";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
     ?>  
     <form action="" method="POST">
     <select name="option_chosen">
        <option>-- Select lot --</option>
        <?php
            while(list($lot_number)=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            echo "<option value=\"".$lot_number."\">".$lot_number."</option>";
        }
       ?>
        </select>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </br>

    <table border="1" id="table">
      <tr>
        <th width=80 height=30>Lot<br/>number</th>
        <th width=110 height=30>Description</th>
        <th width=90 height=30>Pallet<br/>number</th>
        <th width=60 height=30>Net</th>
        <th width=60 height=30>Gross</th>
      </tr>

      <?php 
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST')
 { $option_chosen=$_POST['option_chosen'];
     $query="SELECT * FROM pl_table WHERE lot_number='$option_chosen'";
     $run=mysqli_query($query);
     $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    echo "<tr><td>".$row['lot_number']."</td>";
    echo  "<td>".$row['descr']."</td><td>".$row['pallet_number']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['net']."</td><td>".$['gross']."</td></tr>";

}
?>

         </table>
```