# Select items from database based on Drop-down list

Tags: php, mysql, select

So what i would like to do is selecting multiple items from database based on the choosed option from drop down list,

I have table called articles and there we got the id_article, genre.

Genre got action, adventure, drama ...

And in my code i got a drop down list with genre values and what i would like is when i pick action per example it would automatically select all the items with the genre action, bellow the drop down list.

Already tried to figured it out how to do it and googled aswell and didnt get any info.

Please Help.

What i already done:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/valesilveira.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_valesilveira, $valesilveira);
$query_artigos = "SELECT * FROM artigos WHERE fornecedor like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mySelection']) . "%'";
$artigos = mysql_query($query_artigos, $valesilveira) or die(mysql_error());
$row_artigos = mysql_fetch_assoc($artigos);
$totalRows_artigos = mysql_num_rows($artigos);
?>


<form id="myForm" action="samePage.php" method="post">
<select id="mySelection" name="mySelection" onChange="$('#myForm').submit();">
  <option value="Jimo">Jimo</option>
  <option value="Actipage">Actipage</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="container-outer">
   <div class="container-inner"> 
   <img class="artigo_img" src="images/artigos/<?php echo $row_artigos['id_artigo']; ?>.png" data-artigo-id="<?php echo $row_artigos['id_artigo']; ?>" style="height:130px;"> 
   </div>
</div>

<?php
mysql_free_result($artigos);
?>
```

Its giving me this error Notice: Undefined index: mySelection in C:\xampp\htdocs\valesilveira\test.php on line 35, why?

Help please.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: already add what i have tried so far.

Comment: Please find answer in below link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218749/how-to-retrieve-data-from-drop-down-list-selection-to-a-table

Comment: already tried something new check it out please.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet with html is POST or GET to submit with javascript (on select etc) to post the parameters to the .php script and get a json response back OR  javascript and AJAX to  do essentially the same thing.
The php script will then get the variable, performs query to db and processes them if needed, then returns data you can use.